# Why can I not use two 'if-statements' rather an elif, if only one of the two will execute?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing code to solve a basic problem:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0:
            leap = False
        if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
            leap = True
        else:
            leap = True

    return leap

print(is_leap(2100))
```

My question is with regards to the inner most scope; specifically for the `second 'if statement'`- I know this must be an `'elif'` (and if we don't change it, our answer will be wrong) but I don't see why this is the case.
In my IDE, if I leave the code as is above, the `'leap=False'` for the first `if statement` greys out.

Even though I understand `if vs elif` generally, why can we not just have both as 'if statements'? Because (in this case) based on the logic, for any input we use as an argument, only one of the two if statements will be executed right?

Comment: Because you want the `else` to be run only if *neither* of the preceding if-statements matched. If they are separate if-statements, then the `else` is only attached to the latter.

Comment: One reason is that the code above will return `True` for `2100` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif`'s do not execute if the `if` condition is correct. If you use two `if` statements no matter what they both would be executed.

Not just that, since you have an `else`, the `else` would only be connected to the second if condition, whereas an `elif` would connect the entire block of code.

Comment: Hi U11, it does a lot. But actually one question- is it a problem for the above code if both 'if statements' execute? I can think about scenarios where it would be an issue, but I still don't see why it is a problem above.

Comment: @PatrickChong The main problem above is that "you want the else to be run only if neither of the preceding if-statements matched", as khelwood mentioned, but since you use `if` twice, the `else` would only trigger if the second `if` condition is false, since it's only attached to that statement.